# $cordovaFile file upload error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to upload a picture from my app to the server using `ionic` `$cordovaFile` plugin, Following is my code

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
            options = {
              fileKey: "avatar",
              fileName: "image.png",
              chunkedMode: false,
              mimeType: "image/jpeg"
            }
            $cordovaFile.uploadFile('http://localhost:3001/images/',$scope.imgURI, options)
              .then(function(result){
                console.log("Code = ok");
              }, function(error){
                console.log("Code = " + error);
              }, function(progress){

              })

        }, function(err) {
             //An error occured. Show a message to the user
        });
```

and here is how I added it in the page

```
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

The problem is when I run the project, it prompts me the camera and when I get the picture I'm getting the following error in my console

```
[phonegap] [console.error] Error: Can't find variable: FileTransfer
[phonegap] uploadFile@http://10.1.1.4:3000/js/ng-cordova.min.js:7:24346
[phonegap] http://10.1.1.4:3000/js/controllers/picture_ctrl.js:32:36
...
```

I'm using `phonegap developer app` as the simulator.

What would be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install the cordova file-transfer plugin via:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
```